PWA on Android does not open App clicking on push notification
I have a PWA build with laravel and Google Firebase for push notifications. My service worker looks like this:


importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.1/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
xxx
});

let isStandalone = false;
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(({ notification, data }) => {
    if (isStandalone === true) {
        const notificationTitle = notification.title;
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: notification.body,
        };

        if (notification.image) {
            notificationOptions.icon = notification.image;
        }

        if (data.click_action) {
            notificationOptions.data = {};
            notificationOptions.data.click_action = data.click_action;
        }

        self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    }
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    const notification = event.notification;
    const action = event.action;

    if (action === 'close') {
        notification.close();
    } else {
        const clickAction = notification.data && notification.data.click_action;
        if (clickAction) {
            event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(clientList => {
                for (const client of clientList) {
                    if (client.url === clickAction && 'focus' in client) {
                        return client.focus();
                    }
                }
                if (clients.openWindow) {
                    return clients.openWindow(clickAction);
                }
            }));
        }
        notification.close();
    }
});

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'DISPLAY_MODE') {
        isStandalone = event.data.mode === 'standalone';
    }
});



The push notifications are received, both on iOS and Android, but on Android when the user clicks on the notification nothing happens ... its just closed.
I searched a lot on Google, but i dont find any solution and reason. My code looks like in a lot of examples.
The param "click_action" contain an absolute URL (e.g. https://app.company.com/dashboard) but also when i use relative path its not working.
this i how i send the notification:


return (new FirebaseMessage)
  ->withTitle('Kommst du heute zum Training?')
  ->withBody("{$this->training->name} um {$timeFormat} Uhr")
  ->withAdditionalData([
      'click_action' => route('home')
  ])
  ->withImage(asset('assets/img/icon.png'))
  ->withToken($notifiable->fcm_token)
  ->asNotification();



Does anybody have an idea how to make it work?

No one? its really frustrating not to find a solution and get it working ...
